# Anchor tag having newline because of code-mirror

Tags: html, formatting, anchor, codemirror

Using code mirror to convert my html to formatted html.
To doing this Code mirror is moving all the end HTML tags to the next line.This is creating an issue with the anchor tags as it is moving the end anchor tag to the next line.So while it is being displayed the next line char is also displayed as a white space so we can see a white space next to the content of the anchor tag

Tried to change it via styling but did not have any luck as HTML is rendering the next line as a white space in display

Consider this same HTML

```
<html>
<head>content</head>
<body>
<div>
<a href="sample link">linkname</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code mirror converts this to

```
<html>
   <head>
     content
   </head>
   <body>
        <div>
          <a href="sample link">
              linkname
          </a> 
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to avoid the white space next to the anchor tag that is being rendered because of the new line char via HTML or by code-mirror

Comment: How are you formatting it? I use beautify.js try cdn: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.10.2/beautify-html.js, and configure like so: `html_beautify( (codemirror value), { indent_size: 2 } )`

Comment: The issue is the end anchor tag is moving to the next line , due to code mirror, This by itself is not an issue but while rendering it in a browser .

Comment: Do you have updates on this one? I am experiencing the same issue